# How to convert double value to int when data is passed from Excel

Tags: java

I've below code:

```
public class DataHelper {
     public static List<HashMap<String,String>> data(String filepath,String sheetName) {
          List<HashMap<String,String>> mydata = new ArrayList<>();
          try {
             FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(filepath);
             XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
             XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
             //System.out.println(sheet.getLastRowNum()+"total no of row");
             Row HeaderRow = sheet.getRow(0);
             //System.out.println(sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()+"get the total no of rows");
             for(int i=1;i<sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();i++) {
                 Row currentRow = sheet.getRow(i);
                 HashMap<String,String> currentHash = new HashMap<String,String>();
                 //System.out.println(currentRow.getPhysicalNumberOfCells());
                 for(int j=0;j<currentRow.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();j++) {
                     Cell currentCell = currentRow.getCell(j);
                     switch (currentCell.getCellType()) {
                         case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                         //      
                             currentHash.put(HeaderRow.getCell(j).getStringCellValue(), currentCell.getStringCellValue());

                         case Cell.CELL_TYPE_Numeric:
                             currentHash.put(HeaderRow.getCell(j).getStringCellValue(), currentCell.getStringCellValue());
                             break;  
                     }
                 }
                 mydata.add(currentHash);
             }
             fs.close();
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return mydata;
       }
```

In the above code when integer value is passed from excel sheet it is converting it to double , as I m using hashmap  which takes string arguments i cannot use integer.parseint. So how can i convert the double value to int?

Thanks.

Comment: (int) Double.parseDouble(...) ?

Comment: It is the problem with POI, set the cell type as String

Comment: It should work as you have it now. `getStringValue()` returns a String, which is what you need to put in the map. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: the problem is if i am passing 2 as integer value from excel sheet then it is returning me 2.0 but i need 2 as a result and i cannot parse inside map as it asks for two string arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to rely on Excel/POI's format on getCellStringValue, do:

```
    break;
case Cell.CELL_TYPE_Numeric:
    double x = currentCell.getNumericCellValue();
    //String value = Double.toString(x);
    String value = Long.toString(Math.round(x));
    currentHash.put(HeaderRow.getCell(j).getStringCellValue(), value);
    break;
```

Comment: this would return me a double value but i need integer to be returned

Comment: Added conversion to int.

Comment: On compilation i m getting error under toString in line-Integer.toString(Math.round(x)); and error is  "The method toString(int) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (long)"

Comment: Oh, Math.round returns a long; for String representation just used Long.toString.